# node.removeAction(forKey: xx) is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

by sound on click i say

```
background.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Netherplace.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)), withKey: backgroundSoundKey)
```

by sound off click i say

```
background.removeAction(forKey: backgroundSoundKey)
```

well simply

this removeAction(for key) is not working

any help

thanks

Comment: The action is indeed cancelled(it actually finished when you start playing) but it will not stop the audio.  Use SKAudioNode if you need to suddenly stop sounds

Comment: yup

this one works fine

thanks